# Is there a way to generate a DLL file from Visual Studio Express without explicitly creating a DLL project?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Is there a way to generate a DLL file from Visual Studio Express without explicitly creating a DLL project?

EDIT:
Maybe my thinking process has gone astray on me, but I am trying to setup NUnit, and thought is needed a dll to run it...  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: hum? what do you mean by that?

Comment: well I am using NUnit for the first time and it needs a DLL, DLL's are not generated (as far as I see) from the normal build, on Visual Studio Express.

Comment: Typically, your unit tests should be in a separate project to the main code - this means that your test project can be a dll even if the main  project is an exe...

Comment: How can I use my original project in the test.dll project, though, without a dll for my original project?

Comment: I've just done a test with NUnit, and it is perfectly happy to process tests in an exe assembly.

Comment: You would need a reference from the test project to the code project. VS2005 doesn't make it easy to reference an exe - but it works in VS2008 (so presumably also express 2008).

Comment: If you keep the two projects in the same solution, you can just add a project reference between the two, which is even easier.

Comment: I started a separate project in the same solution, and added a reference to the original project from the test project, tomorrow I will try to run the tests! Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Marc, not sure if you'll find this comment, but I have gotten the NUnit working, for tests like Assert.AreEquals(1, 1).  But when it tries to link to my other project (which I referenced like you explained) it raises a FileNotFound exception when trying to load the assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the Project Properties|Application|Output Type to either Windows Application, Console Application or Class Library, thus by selecting Class Library you will output a DLL.

I struggle to think why you'd want to do this though?

Answer (score 1):

How do you mean? What exactly are you after?

You can create an exe project and change the output type (project properties)... or you can use `csc /target:library` at the command line...