# visual c# - Add visual web developer project as a reference

Tags: project, visual-web-developer, visual-c#-express-2010

I want to create a winform/console application inside visual c# that uses class library project from visual web developer, how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is this the expresss Vis Web Dev? I don't think it generates .dlls

Comment: yes, the express. So there is no normal way to make tests scripts for the web project from the Console? thanks

Comment: See this question for an answer. I was wrong... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514900/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-dll-file-from-visual-studio-express-without-explicit

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the references folder in the Solution Explorer pane
2. Click Add Reference in the menu that appears
3. Select the Browse tab
4. Browse to the file you'd like to include
5. Click OK

You're done!  The file has been added to your references.